# linking user profile with other class in django (in postgresql db)

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am pretty new to django and I am trying to get 2 classes to work together in the database. More precisely, I want users to be able to create devices, and then link the user and the device in the database (I'm using postgresql database)

models.py

```
class Device(models.Model):
    deviceNb = models.CharField(max_length = 50, null=True)
    temperature = models.IntegerField()
    battery = models.IntegerField()

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    profession= models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    device = models.OneToOneField(Device, null=True) # null = true is to allow null values for devices

User.profile = property(lambda u : UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])
```

forms.py

```
class DeviceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Device
        fields = ('deviceNb', 'temperature', 'battery',)


class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('profession', )
```

views.py

```
def user_profile(request):
    user = request.user
    profile = user.profile
    device = profile.device
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #we want to populate the form with the original instance of the profile model and insert POST info on top of it
        device_form = DeviceForm(request.POST, instance=device)

        if device_form.is_valid():
            dev = device_form.save()
            device = dev
            form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=profile)

            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                #to go back to check that the info has changed
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/loggedin')

    else: 
        form = UserProfileForm(instance=profile)
        device_form = DeviceForm(instance=device)

    args = {}

    args['form'] = form
    args['device_form'] = device_form

    return render(request, 'profile.html', args)
```

Now, in postgresql, I have the following tables:

userprofile_userprofile (which contains the following table columns):

```
id  : OK (filled)
user_id : OK (filled)
device_id : PROBLEM : NOT FILLED
profession : OK (filled)
```

userprofile_device (which contains the following table columns):

```
id : OK 
temperature: OK 
battery: OK 
deviceNb : OK
```

The thing is, i want to be able to have a device Id associated with what the user has already created so that the user and the device are both linked

Comment: It seems like your `UserProfile` doesn't have a device. Based upon the **models.py** relationship above, you should have access to the device id by doing `user_profile.device.id` in python.

Answer (score 1):

When you call 'save' in a modelform then the model is saved in database and returned.
But in your code you create and instance of UserProfileForm without a previous created device.
Here one way to solve the problem

```
...
if request.method == 'POST':
    device_form = DeviceForm(request.POST, instance = device)

    if device_form.is_valid():
        device = device_form.save()
        request.user.profile.device = device
        form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/loggedin')
        else:
            device.delete()
            not_valid_form = True
    else:
        not_valid_device_form = True
    if not_valid_form or not_valid_device_form: # when this is a get request
        ...
```

Comment: unfortunately this did not work for me. The device id is still not in my userprofile_userprofile column called device_id

Comment: the problem is : request.user.profile.device = device
seems to not really work. Because when i print device.id (it is the proper id) 
but when i print request.user.profile.device, it remains none

Answer (score 1):

I used wilkus solution, but with a small twist,

added the following lines

```
if form.is_valid():
      prof = form.save(commit=False)
      prof.device_id = device
      prof.save()
```

This allows you to return an object from the form.save(commit=false) without sending it to the database, then i use that instance to change device_id (which is not in the form fields obviously) and then, save it (and thus sending to the db)

Therefore, the views.py is :

```
def user_profile(request):
    user = request.user
    profile = user.profile
    device = profile.device
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #we want to populate the form with the original instance of the profile model and insert POST info on top of it
        device_form = DeviceForm(request.POST, instance=device)

        if device_form.is_valid():
            dev = device_form.save()
            form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=profile)

            if form.is_valid():
                prof = form.save(commit=False)
                prof.device_id = dev
                prof.save()

                #to go back to check that the info has changed
                return render_to_response('loggedin.html', {'real_device': dev, 'profile_prof': request.user.profile.profession, 'user_device': request.user.profile.device})

    else: # when this is a get request
          #this is the preferred way to get a users info, it is stored that way
        #if we have a user that has already selected info, it will pass in this info
        form = UserProfileForm(instance=profile)
        device_form = DeviceForm(instance=device)

    args = {}

    args['form'] = form
    args['device_form'] = device_form

    return render(request, 'profile.html', args)
```